# WP8 DataBound app shows "runtime one", "runtime two"

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

I am testing the DataboundApp template for my app. I've changed the records in the SampleData file. The Designer shows the records correctly (on MainPage.xaml), but when i'm running it on device, it only shows "runtime one" "runtime two" "runtime three" etc. instead of my edited datas. What's the problem here?

I'm talking about the raw DataboundApp template, i've just edited the database file.

Comment: when you said, i change the sample data file. What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

The designer data is not same in this application. Look LoadData() methode in mainViewModel.

Comment: I see now. And how can I use the data in MainViewModelSampleData.xaml, for example? I've deleted the records in mainViewModel LoadData(), the designer still shows my records correctly, and now the real device shows nothing. I would make, say, 10 pages, and use data from xamls like MainViewModelSampleData for each page. Should i make 10 unique viewmodels too, or is there any way to add records to MainViewModel with xamls?

Comment: MainViewModelSampleData.xaml is only use here for see anything in your designer. It's like design data. If you want to have data when your launch your have you need to add yours items in items list. I edit my response for an exemple.

Comment: The better way is to create Model ViewModel View. So create your model  match with your xml object and when your parse your xml, create a liste of your modelObject and set itemSource.